PyGame, Pywin32 API and PyOpenGL transparency error
I am trying to make a transparent screen by hide the background color with win32api.
It works with pygame in 2D. However, when I use pyopengl to make a 3D platform, the background isn't transparent.
I use windows 7 64bits and python 2.7.
Here is the code for the main.py:
import sys, tran
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.constants import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
import os
import pygame as pg

# IMPORT OBJECT LOADER
from objLoader import *

pg.init()
viewport = (800,600)
hx = viewport[0]/2
hy = viewport[1]/2
srf = pg.display.set_mode(viewport, OPENGL | DOUBLEBUF)

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION,  (-40, 200, 100, 0.0))
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, (0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0))
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0))
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)           

obj = OBJ('T80obj.obj', swapyz=True)

clock = pg.time.Clock()

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
width, height = viewport
gluPerspective(90.0, width/float(height), 1, 100.0)
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)

rx, ry = (0,0)
tx, ty = (0,0)
zpos = 5
rotate = move = False

hwnd = pg.display.get_wm_info()["window"]

r,g,b = 0,0,0

while 1:
    clock.tick(30)
    for e in pg.event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE:
            sys.exit()
        elif e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if e.button == 4: zpos = max(1, zpos-1)
            elif e.button == 5: zpos += 1
            elif e.button == 1: rotate = True
            elif e.button == 3: move = True
        elif e.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if e.button == 1: rotate = False
            elif e.button == 3: move = False
        elif e.type == MOUSEMOTION:
            i, j = e.rel
            if rotate:
                rx += i
                ry += j
            if move:
                tx += i
                ty -= j
    
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    glLoadIdentity()

    # RENDER OBJECT
    glTranslate(tx/20., ty/20., - zpos)
    glRotate(ry, 1, 0, 0)
    glRotate(rx, 0, 1, 0)
    glCallList(obj.gl_list)
    pg.draw.rect(srf, (255,0,0), (50, 50, 100, 100), 2)

    r += 1;
    g += 1;
    b += 1;
    print(r,g,b)
    # tran.tran(hwnd,(r,g,b,));

    pg.display.flip()
    pg.draw.rect(srf, (255,0,0), (50, 50, 100, 100), 2)

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0)
    tran.tran(hwnd,(0,0,0))

And objLoader.py:
import pygame
from tqdm import tqdm
from OpenGL.GL import *

def MTL(filename):
    contents = {}
    mtl = None
    for line in open(filename, "r"):
        if line.startswith('#'): continue
        values = line.split()
        if not values: continue
        if values[0] == 'newmtl':
            mtl = contents[values[1]] = {}
        elif mtl is None:
            raise ValueError, "mtl file doesn't start with newmtl stmt"
        elif values[0] == 'map_Kd':
            # load the texture referred to by this declaration
            mtl[values[0]] = values[1]
            surf = pygame.image.load(mtl['map_Kd'])
            image = pygame.image.tostring(surf, 'RGBA', 1)
            ix, iy = surf.get_rect().size
            texid = mtl['texture_Kd'] = glGenTextures(1)
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid)
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                GL_LINEAR)
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                GL_LINEAR)
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, ix, iy, 0, GL_RGBA,
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image)
        else:
            mtl[values[0]] = map(float, values[1:])
    return contents

class OBJ:
    def __init__(self, filename, swapyz=False):
        """Loads a Wavefront OBJ file. """
        self.vertices = []
        self.normals = []
        self.texcoords = []
        self.faces = []

        material = None
        for line in open(filename, "r"):
            if line.startswith('#'): continue
            values = line.split()
            if not values: continue
            if values[0] == 'v':
                v = map(float, values[1:4])
                if swapyz:
                    v = v[0], v[2], v[1]
                self.vertices.append(v)
            elif values[0] == 'vn':
                v = map(float, values[1:4])
                if swapyz:
                    v = v[0], v[2], v[1]
                self.normals.append(v)
            elif values[0] == 'vt':
                self.texcoords.append(map(float, values[1:3]))
            elif values[0] in ('usemtl', 'usemat'):
                material = values[1]
            elif values[0] == 'mtllib':
                self.mtl = MTL(values[1])
            elif values[0] == 'f':
                face = []
                texcoords = []
                norms = []
                for v in values[1:]:
                    w = v.split('/')
                    face.append(int(w[0]))
                    if len(w) >= 2 and len(w[1]) > 0:
                        texcoords.append(int(w[1]))
                    else:
                        texcoords.append(0)
                    if len(w) >= 3 and len(w[2]) > 0:
                        norms.append(int(w[2]))
                    else:
                        norms.append(0)
                self.faces.append((face, norms, texcoords, material))

        self.gl_list = glGenLists(1)
        glNewList(self.gl_list, GL_COMPILE)
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glFrontFace(GL_CCW)
        for face in tqdm(self.faces):
            vertices, normals, texture_coords, material = face
            # print(self.mtl)
            mtl = self.mtl[material]
            if 'texture_Kd' in mtl:
                # use diffuse texmap
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mtl['texture_Kd'])
            else:
                # just use diffuse colour
                glColor(*mtl['Kd'])

            glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
            for i in range(len(vertices)):
                if normals[i] > 0:
                    glNormal3fv(self.normals[normals[i] - 1])
                if texture_coords[i] > 0:
                    glTexCoord2fv(self.texcoords[texture_coords[i] - 1])
                glVertex3fv(self.vertices[vertices[i] - 1])
            glEnd()
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glEndList()

You can use your own model, just need .obj and .mlt file then edit it in the line 33.
In the result, you can see that the background didn't transparent.


Are you aware that Python 2.7 reached its end of life four years ago? In an ironic coincidence, support for your Windows 7 ended only 13 days later. You're using an outdated language on an outdated OS. Please, please, please update!
